# Mapping properties onto an IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata

We have an API with `IQueryable<T>` resources because we work with OData. My boss requires the resources to be exposed to also have additional information which is not available in the database.

OData allows one to only select the information they need, it does this by mapping a $select=Quantity query parameter to LINQ: performing a .Select(s => s.Quantity). This will of course not work since LINQ to Entities will complain the column does not exist in the database.

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Quantity
    {
        get { return SubItems.Count; }
        set {}
    }

    public virtual ICollection<SubItem> SubItems { get; set; }
}
```

I need a way around this restriction. I have looked into AutoMapper however it fails when using `.ProjectTo()` with their `IValueResolver`. I need `IValueResolver` because some of the extra properties are not so easily mapped onto a SQL structure, for example:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return Convert(DescriptionId); }
        set {}
    }

    public int DescriptionId { get; set; }
}

public string Convert(int value)
{
    switch(value)
    {
        case 1:
            return "1";
        default:
            return "0";
    }
}
```

I have looked into the code below as well but this fails with `System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot apply ODataQueryOptions of 'DtoItem' to IQueryable of 'Item'. Parameter name: query'`. Reversing the data types I manage to get a result but I cannot return this of course as the data type is not matching with my controller function. I do however need the `ODataQueryOptions` of `DtoItem` otherwise I will not have access to $select any of those extra fields because it will not know about them. But then I am back to square one on how would OData even apply those options to an item of a different type.

```
public IQueryable<Item> Get(ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
{
    IQueryable<Item> items = (IQueryable<Item>) queryOptions.ApplyTo(repositoryItem.Select());

    return mapper.Map<List<DtoItem>>(items.ToList()).AsQueryable(); // Cannot convert DtoItem to Item but of course I want to return DtoItem
}
```

What is necessary for me to accomplish this requirement? I have looked into Entity Framework but it seems very much sealed of. I'm not even sure if modifying the expression tree would be enough. I'd still have to add the values somehow during materialization.

Comment: https://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thanks I will have a look.